# How to add NCSU FreePDK45 to Cadence Virtuoso Library?

Tags: cadence, virtuoso

I'm looking for a comprehensive guide on how to add FreePDK45 to Cadence Virtuoso Library (2015 version). The installation guides included are not clear for first timers, and other resources available online are about installing other PDKs that -seem- not to follow the same steps for FreePDK45.
So, how to install any PDK in general?
How to install FreePDK45 specifically ?
Thanks !

Comment: *Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!* - links and explanations needed so that folk making an answer know explicitly what you have done to help yourself.

Comment: @Andyaka of course I did. people that are familiar with the subject will easily understand.

Comment: Read this: *Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers* - nobody really knows what you've done and there's nothing that guides someone who may answer from wasting your time with stuff you've already uncovered.